# Custom WCF Service responds with 413 Request Entity too large

Tags: 2013, wcf

I have a custom WCF service that external services are using to send generated documents through for storage in SharePoint.

Small files are working fine, but anything over 64KB is getting rejected with: (413) Request Entity too large.

Since I have used a factory in my svc, I have configured a feature and then in the Installed event for the feature I have put the following code:

```
SPWebService contentService = SPWebService.ContentService;
contentService.ClientRequestServiceSettings.MaxReceivedMessageSize = -1;

SPWcfServiceSettings settings = new SPWcfServiceSettings();

if (contentService.WcfServiceSettings.ContainsKey("dmsservice.svc"))
{
    settings = contentService.WcfServiceSettings["dmsservice.svc"];
}

settings.MaxReceivedMessageSize = Int32.MaxValue;
settings.MaxBufferSize = Int32.MaxValue;
settings.ReaderQuotasMaxStringContentLength = Int32.MaxValue;
settings.ReaderQuotasMaxArrayLength = Int32.MaxValue;
settings.ReaderQuotasMaxBytesPerRead = Int32.MaxValue;           

contentService.WcfServiceSettings["dmsservice.svc"] = settings;
contentService.Update(true);
```

However, even though all the posts i have found indicate that the above should work, it is not. So what am I missing in order to get this service to accept bigger files?

Answer (score 5):

Heres the sample from the Blog:

Generate a class like this:

```
public class CustomMultipleBaseAddressWebServiceHostFactory : Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Services.MultipleBaseAddressWebServiceHostFactory
    {
        protected override System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
        {
            return new CustomMultipleBaseServiceHost(serviceType, baseAddresses);
        }
    }

    public class CustomMultipleBaseServiceHost : Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Services.MultipleBaseAddressWebServiceHost
    {
        public CustomMultipleBaseServiceHost(Type serviceType, params Uri[] baseAddresses)
            : base(serviceType, baseAddresses)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnOpening()
        {
            base.OnOpening();

            foreach (ServiceEndpoint endpoint in this.Description.Endpoints)
            {

                IncreaseFileUploadSize(endpoint);

            }
        }

        private static void IncreaseFileUploadSize(ServiceEndpoint endpoint) {
            var customBinding = endpoint.Binding as WebHttpBinding;
            if (customBinding != null)
            {
              customBinding.MaxBufferSize = Int32.MaxValue;
              customBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = Int32.MaxValue;
            }
        }
```

And then use it in the yourservice.svc:

```
<%@ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true"
Service="NameSpaceOfMyService.MyServiceClassName, $SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$"
Factory="NameSpaceOfMyServiceHostFactory.MyServiceHostFactoryClassName, $SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>
```

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem on SharePoint 2013. If I create a custom Service factory based on SharePoint factory and override config settings (MaxReceivedMessageSize) the error gone.

More info: http://cameron-verhelst.be/blog/2014/10/19/hosting-a-wcf-service-in-sharepoint-with-a-spcontext/

Comment: The link may contain the solution, but can you please add some brief description.

Answer (score 0):

If it will be useful to somebody. 
I do not quite understand where to put the code from the comment above. After I put it in a file "CodeBehind" everything worked fine.
So, my cs looks like:
[image]